# application react with docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose

I am putting a react application to use docker-compose.
The Dockerfile file and the docker-compose.yml were created but an error is occurring to build the application.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm ci
EXPOSE 3000
# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  app:
    container_name: react_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

The folder architecture is:

docker-compose.yml
docker
app/package.json
app/src/

when executing the command docker-compose up -d --build the error below occurs.

> Building app Step 1/5 : FROM node:8  ---> 8eeadf3757f4 Step 2/5 :
> WORKDIR /usr/src/app  ---> Running in 1420513ebefb Removing
> intermediate container 1420513ebefb  ---> f46f192dd592 Step 3/5 : RUN
> npm ci  ---> Running in edb7041c8ba5 npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR!
> syscall open npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json npm ERR! errno -2
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/usr/src/spa/package.json' npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not
> being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-25T19_38_16_569Z-debug.log ERROR: Service
> 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm ci' returned a
> non-zero code: 254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy your project files to the inside of the docker container.
The below code will help to fix your problem.

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Halil error is Step 4/7 : RUN npm ci
 ---> Running in 00e1df66522d
npm ERR! cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or later to generate it, then try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-25T20_45_01_752Z-debug.log

Comment: I will change the post with the insertion and the new error.

Comment: if you don't have package-lock.json, you should use `npm install` instead of using `npm ci`. Change with `npm install`