# React application: docker works but not docker compose

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose

I developed a React UI named frontend for a project on a mac:

```
myproject
├── frontend
│  ├── README.md
│  ├── dev.frontend.dockerfile
│  ├── docker-compose.yml
│  ├── package-lock.json
│  ├── package.json
│  ├── public
│  ├── src
│  └── tsconfig.json
```

From /frontend, I can:

1. use `docker` to build an image and run/create a container
2. use `docker compose` to run frontend as a service.

Both work fine!

dev.frontend.dockerfile

```
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY public  /app/public
COPY package.json /app
COPY package-lock.json /app

RUN npm install
COPY . ./

RUN pwd && ls -ltra 
RUN ls -ltra public

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '1.0'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dev.frontend.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

My goal is to run all services under /myproject with docker compose as I pull other services in. As a first step, I tried moving the docker-compose.yml file up one level to /myproject:

```
myproject
├── docker-compose.yml          <--- moved up
├── frontend
│  ├── README.md
│  ├── dev.frontend.dockerfile
│  ├── package-lock.json
│  ├── package.json
│  ├── public
│  ├── src
│  └── tsconfig.json
└── node_modules                <--- created during build - huh?
```

docker-compose.yml at /myproject:

```
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend              <--- only change
      dockerfile: dev.frontend.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

I only updated the build `context`. My expectation was that making that one change would tell compose where the frontend service dockerfile was and in which context to build that service, i.e., /frontend. But when I ran it, it returned the error below:

```
% docker compose up --build --force-recreate
[+] Building 20.3s (15/15) FINISHED                                                  
 => [internal] load build definition from dev.frontend.dockerfile                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 303B                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 95B                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20-alpine                                                                       1.4s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring context: 1.47MB                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [1/9] FROM docker.io/library/node:20-alpine@sha256:8e015de364a2eb2ed7c52a558e9f716dcb615560ffd132234087c10ccc1f2c63     2.5s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:20-alpine@sha256:8e015de364a2eb2ed7c52a558e9f716dcb615560ffd132234087c10ccc1f2c63     0.0s
 => => sha256:7035a9761f602cac8176359dccbac6a752b4da17f56dab1a144a04d9f122cf95 2.34MB / 2.34MB                              0.3s
 => => sha256:8e015de364a2eb2ed7c52a558e9f716dcb615560ffd132234087c10ccc1f2c63 1.43kB / 1.43kB                              0.0s
 => => sha256:12a9b2ab331c96e57763a15336c1360002d3a2fbca1f6fdc0334581bca20dbea 1.16kB / 1.16kB                              0.0s
 => => sha256:1e9578ee4112c5d9884fe0e6adcaf0cf6cf71d9a70f2e68aa0a8ff12f9e1f7d5 6.79kB / 6.79kB                              0.0s
 => => sha256:579b34f0a95bb83b3acd6b3249ddc52c3d80f5c84b13c944e9e324feb86dd329 3.33MB / 3.33MB                              0.2s
 => => sha256:2b81652d645d4a1301c33f155cdeeb9189182cc89dc4d7e65d7b164a43389dbd 50.03MB / 50.03MB                            1.2s
 => => extracting sha256:579b34f0a95bb83b3acd6b3249ddc52c3d80f5c84b13c944e9e324feb86dd329                                   0.1s
 => => sha256:ccca1742947cf696d50b5e5197157a7aa16a1bf9a9edaefef3db2e10c6da7c41 448B / 448B                                  0.5s
 => => extracting sha256:2b81652d645d4a1301c33f155cdeeb9189182cc89dc4d7e65d7b164a43389dbd                                   1.0s
 => => extracting sha256:7035a9761f602cac8176359dccbac6a752b4da17f56dab1a144a04d9f122cf95                                   0.1s
 => => extracting sha256:ccca1742947cf696d50b5e5197157a7aa16a1bf9a9edaefef3db2e10c6da7c41                                   0.0s
 => [2/9] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                      0.2s
 => [3/9] COPY public  /app/public                                                                                          0.0s
 => [4/9] COPY package.json /app                                                                                            0.0s
 => [5/9] COPY package-lock.json /app                                                                                       0.0s
 => [6/9] RUN npm install                                                                                                   12.9s
 => [7/9] COPY . ./                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [8/9] RUN pwd && ls -ltra                                                                                               0.1s
 => [9/9] RUN ls -ltra public                                                                                               0.3s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                      2.7s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                     2.7s
 => => writing image sha256:1c386e305c2799f6dda7aad00b243f5ef6ebd614d680aefaac9599395add1517                                0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/timeshare-frontend                                                                       0.0s
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Network timeshare_default  Created                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 ⠿ Container frontend         Created                                                                                       3.1s
Attaching to frontend
frontend  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
frontend  | npm ERR! syscall open
frontend  | npm ERR! path /app/package.json
frontend  | npm ERR! errno -2
frontend  | npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
frontend  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
frontend  | npm ERR! enoent 
frontend  | 
frontend  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-11-15T13_41_32_726Z-debug-0.log
frontend exited with code 254
```

I saw tickets like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64528123/application-react-with-docker-compose), but did not help.

How do I fix this build?

*side note*: I did not expect node_modules to be created in /myproject

Comment: I'd recommend deleting the `volumes:` block.  Since your image already contains the application code, there's no need to overwrite it with a bind mount.

Comment: @DavidMaze that did it, thanks.